# Why is $2\cos^210^\circ -2\cos^220^\circ =\sin10^\circ$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was to simplify an expression, I came to this:

$$X=2\cos^210^\circ -2\cos^220^\circ$$

But, I couldn't simplify it further.

I checked the answer and it was $\sin10^\circ$. But I can't understand why.

Can anyone help?

---

EDIT:
$\theta$ was $10^\circ$. I myself generalized it.

The two sides are not equivalent. So $10^\circ$ seems to have a special characteristic which we should use here.

Comment: Check $\theta =\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: There's a mistake somewhere ; LHS is even, RHS is odd. What was the expression to simplify?

Comment: @Fib1123 It was 10.

Comment: @D.Thomine Yes. It was an equation. Not an Identity. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write our equation as:
\begin{align}
2\cos^210^\circ -2\cos^2 20^\circ &= 2(\cos 10^\circ + \cos 20^\circ)(\cos 10^\circ -\cos 20^\circ)\\
&=2(2\cos 15^\circ \cos 5^\circ)(2\sin 15^\circ \sin 5^\circ)\\
&=8\sin 15^\circ \cos 15^\circ \sin 5^\circ \cos 5^\circ\\
&= 2(2\sin 15^\circ \cos 15^\circ)(2\sin 5^\circ \cos 5^\circ)\\
&= 2\sin 30^\circ \sin 10^\circ\\
&= \sin 10^\circ. 
\end{align}
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [“sum to product formulas”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)
\begin{align}
\cos10^\circ+\cos20^\circ&=2\cos15^\circ\cos5^\circ\\
\cos10^\circ-\cos20^\circ&=2\sin15^\circ\sin5^\circ
\end{align}
so your expression is
$$
8\sin15^\circ\cos15^\circ\sin5^\circ\cos5^\circ=
2\sin30^\circ\sin10^\circ=\sin10^\circ
$$
In general,
$$
2(\cos^2\theta-\cos^22\theta)=
8\sin\frac{3\theta}{2}\cos\frac{3\theta}{2}
\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}
=
2\sin3\theta\sin\theta
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
X &=2 \cos^210^\circ-1-(2 \cos^220^\circ-1)\\
  &= \cos 20^\circ-\cos40^\circ\\
  &=2 \sin30^\circ \sin10^\circ\\
  &=2\cdot\tfrac12\cdot \sin10^\circ.
\end{align}